# Oracle decode null date variable

Tags: oracle

I have a query as part of a larger function and having trouble making `DECODE` work with null dates. This portion of my query is in the `WHERE` condition of the query:

```
NVL(datRunDate,SYSDATE) 
BETWEEN NVL(EFFECTIVE_DATE,NVL(datRunDate,SYSDATE-1)) 
AND DECODE(STOP_DATE, NULL, NVL(datRunDate,SYSDATE + 1), STOP_DATE + (59/86400))
```

Where:

```
datRunDate     DATE
EFFECTIVE_DATE DATE
STOP_DATE      DATE
```

My issue is that the `STOP_DATE` is typically `NULL` and the `DECODE` doesn't work. Any ideas / help to work around this is appreciated.

**EDIT**
Adding some sample data as suggested:

```
datRunDate      2016-01-14 06:41:54
EFFECTIVE_DATE  2013-04-01 09:53:00
STOP_DATE       NULL
```

***EDIT2***
Adding the entire query text here as the problem probably lies here. Note: I have replaced the variables manually. These variables are populated before this query with simple `SELECT INTO` statements.

```
datRunDate      DATE;   

SELECT COMP_DATE INTO datRunDate where IDL_SEQ = 2320;
```

[image]

[image]

```
SELECT EFFECTIVE_DATE, STOP_DATE from IDLS where IDL_SEQ = 2320;
```

[image]

[image]

`DESC IDL_TABLE`

[image]

`DESC SCHEDULES`  COMP_DATE = datRunDate

[image]
...

```
    SELECT I.IDL_SEQ          
    FROM IDLS I, IDL_CMPS IC
    WHERE I.RECORD_TYPE = 'M' 
    AND IC.IDL_SEQ = I.IDL_SEQ
    AND IC.CMP = '71-43-2'
    AND I.METHOD = 'N0'           
    AND ((I.RUN_INSTRU = '') OR (I.RUN_INSTRU IS NULL))
    AND ((I.PREP_METHOD = 'K9') OR (I.PREP_METHOD IS NULL))
    AND ((I.MATRIX = 'SO') OR (I.MATRIX IS NULL))
    AND ((I.COLUMN_ID = '') OR (I.COLUMN_ID IS NULL)) 
    AND COALESCE(datRunDate, SYSDATE)
    BETWEEN COALESCE(I.EFFECTIVE_DATE, datRunDate, SYSDATE - 1) 
    AND COALESCE(I.STOP_DATE + (59/86400), datRunDate, SYSDATE + 1) 
    AND ((I.SAMPLE_TYPE = 'SAMPLE') OR (SAMPLE_TYPE IS NULL))
    AND ((I.CUST_SAMPLE_ID = 'SB-7') OR (CUST_SAMPLE_ID IS NULL))
    AND ((I.LOCATION = '') OR (LOCATION IS NULL))          
    AND (
         (OTHER_CRITERIA IS NOT NULL AND 404324 IS NOT NULL AND OTHER_CRITERIA = 'P|'||404324) OR
         (OTHER_CRITERIA IS NOT NULL AND 28936 IS NOT NULL AND OTHER_CRITERIA = 'R|'||28936) OR
         (OTHER_CRITERIA IS NOT NULL AND 'ECO' IS NOT NULL AND OTHER_CRITERIA = 'C|'||'ECO') OR
         (OTHER_CRITERIA IS NULL));
```

Now when I run this I get: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE

Comment: Are you sure you don't have "default" values in your date fields? decode seems to work well even with null dates; for example, this gives sysdate: `select decode (null, null, sysdate, sysdate - 100) from dual`

Comment: All the values in `datRunDate` and `EFFECTIVE_DATE` are dates.

Comment: They are dates, ok, but is it possible that you have, for example, 01/01/0001 instead of null?

Comment: Good question, am looking now but this query is iterated so each pass would have different values. The first 20 or so I looked at individually looked correct.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to include some sample data; with the dates formatted to show the full year and the time (`SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`). To help you debug you can also query those columns plus the three expressions so you can compare what they produce with what you expect to see.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for the response, I added the first sample data with the dates formatted. This should work using `coalesce` as shown below, just not seeing the error.

Comment: Which error aren't you seeing? Your query (or Gordon's) match a row with those values. So I'm not really sure what problem you are having or quite what you are asking.

Comment: That's the issue, it doesn't match anything and returns nothing. The `datRunDate` is a variable that the value is selected into, the Effective/Stop Dates are pulled directly from the table. The last part that evaluates the `STOP_DATE` just doesn't evaluate - which is my issue. If I replace the last condition as stated in my response to the answer below, it does work.

Comment: @random_answer_guy - but I tried with a  CTE and with those values your query *does* find a row. So something is wrong or missing. Can you create a complete example showing the table, data, how you're getting the variable value, and how you're running and checking the query?

Comment: @AlexPoole I have added my complete query to the description, hopefully will help.

Comment: The code you posted in edit 2 is using string `'14-Jan-16'`, which is not a date and can't be implicitly converted to a date where you've used it. If you replace the three places you have that with `cast(timestamp '2016-01-14 06:41:54' as date)` you won't get that error. You haven't shown the tables or data. With some made-up CTEs with effective date 2013-04-01 09:53:00 that query finds data, as it is and with the `coalesce(...)` replaced with the same fixed datRunDate value. So I still have no idea what your actual problem is.

Comment: Added as much info as I could that is relevant to the date comparison now. And thanks for taking the time, not trying to make the question harder than it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121202/discussion-between-alex-poole-and-random-answer-guy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
COALESCE(datRunDate, SYSDATE) BETWEEN COALESCE(EFFECTIVE_DATE, datRunDate, SYSDATE - 1) AND
                                      COALESCE(STOP_DATE + (59/86400), dateRunDate, SYSDATE + 1)
```

The ANSI standard function `COALESCE()` is simpler than using `NVL()` and `DECODE()` (which should be obsoleted anyway).

Comment: Thanks for this, but it still doesn't return anything for me. If I change the last condition `COALESCE(STOP_DATE + (59/86400), dateRunDate, SYSDATE + 1)` to simply `datRunDate` it works fine.

Comment: @random_answer_guy . . . I'm pretty sure the logic in your code is implemented in this answer.  I can't speak to what the logic *should* be based on unknown requirements.

Comment: This was the correct answer, I had another issue that made it appear this was failing, thanks for the help.